# Python currency converter - how to handle the amount being empty

Tags: python, flask

I built a very simple currency converter with Python/Flask. I'm using a library called [forex-python](https://forex-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). Everything works, but the app crashes when the user leaves the 'amount' empty, and I get a Python error `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

I have `try.. except` for `ValueError` and `TypeError`, but they don't work. I'm guessing, when the user leaves 'amount' empty, it's treated as a string, and python can't convert that to `float`

So how do I handle this gracefully? I simply wanna redirect the user to `'/'` and show them a flash message.

Here is the code:

```
@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    conv_from = request.form['conv_from']
    conv_to = request.form['conv_to']
    amount = float(request.form['amount'])
    
    rates = CurrencyRates()
    codes = CurrencyCodes()
    
    try:
        results = round(rates.convert(conv_from, conv_to, amount), 2)
        symbol = codes.get_symbol(conv_to)
        return render_template("/results.html", conv_from=conv_from, conv_to=conv_to, amount=amount, results=results, symbol=symbol)
    except RatesNotAvailableError:
        flash("Please enter a valid currency")
        return redirect('/')
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        flash("Oops something went wrong")
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: You can use `amount = request.form.get('amount', type=float)` instead and it will not raise an exception, but it will return `None` if it does not exist. Then you can do checks like `if amount is None: ....`

Answer (score 0):

You are not casting in your try/except block. Just change the location of the `amount` variable *(where you are casting it using the `float` method)* so that it is in the try/except block and the exception should get handled.

So the fix would be:

```py
@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    conv_from = request.form['conv_from']
    conv_to = request.form['conv_to']
    
    rates = CurrencyRates()
    codes = CurrencyCodes()
    
    try:
        amount = float(request.form['amount'])
        results = round(rates.convert(conv_from, conv_to, amount), 2)
        symbol = codes.get_symbol(conv_to)
        return render_template("/results.html", conv_from=conv_from, conv_to=conv_to, amount=amount, results=results, symbol=symbol)
    except RatesNotAvailableError:
        flash("Please enter a valid currency")
        return redirect('/')
    except ValueError:
        flash("Invalid amount provided!")
        return redirect('/')
    except TypeError:
        flash("Oops something went wrong")
        return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `if` statement to check if the string is empty is enough:

```
@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    conv_from = request.form['conv_from']
    conv_to = request.form['conv_to']
    if request.form['amount'] == "":
        print("Enter a valid amount")
        return False
    else:
        amount = float(request.form['amount'])
    
    rates = CurrencyRates()
    codes = CurrencyCodes()
    
    try:
        results = round(rates.convert(conv_from, conv_to, amount), 2)
        symbol = codes.get_symbol(conv_to)
        return render_template("/results.html", conv_from=conv_from, conv_to=conv_to, amount=amount, results=results, symbol=symbol)
    except RatesNotAvailableError:
        flash("Please enter a valid currency")
        return redirect('/')
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        flash("Oops something went wrong")
        return redirect('/')
```

However, this only checks if the string is empty. If I tried to input 5 USD but typed 5xyz that would not be handled. In that case, a try/catch block like this will also work.

```
@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    conv_from = request.form['conv_from']
    conv_to = request.form['conv_to']
    try:
        amount = float(request.form['amount'])
    except:
        print("Not a valid amount")
    rates = CurrencyRates()
    codes = CurrencyCodes()
    try:
        results = round(rates.convert(conv_from, conv_to, amount), 2)
        symbol = codes.get_symbol(conv_to)
        return render_template("/results.html", conv_from=conv_from, conv_to=conv_to, amount=amount, results=results, symbol=symbol)
    except RatesNotAvailableError:
        flash("Please enter a valid currency")
        return redirect('/')
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        flash("Oops something went wrong")
        return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the cleanest solution, you can use `request.form.get()` for your other `request.form` variables too if you want to.

`request.form.get()` returns `None` if the specified key does not exist or if the variable type does not match the specified `type` in `request.form.get()`.

Python code:

```py
@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    conv_from = request.form['conv_from']
    conv_to = request.form['conv_to']
    amount = request.form.get('amount', type=float)

    if amount is None:
        flash('Please enter a valid amount!')
        return redirect('/')
    
    rates = CurrencyRates()
    codes = CurrencyCodes()
    
    try:
        results = round(rates.convert(conv_from, conv_to, amount), 2)
        symbol = codes.get_symbol(conv_to)
        return render_template("/results.html", conv_from=conv_from, conv_to=conv_to, amount=amount, results=results, symbol=symbol)
    except RatesNotAvailableError:
        flash("Please enter a valid currency")
        return redirect('/')
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        flash("Oops something went wrong")
        return redirect('/')
```